# Filter an angular.js array based on range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an angular.js array of 3 products and a range slider that is counting from `0 - 20` with a step of `1`.  I need to make it so, as I slide the range slider it will filter my array and only show products with the height property that fits in that category.

ie: filtering `0` to `10` would show anything with a height of `0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

*This is not required for my question but if it was possible to append `inches` to the end of the value, I would appreciate that help as well.*

**My html is just a basic range slider set up:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" style="min-height: 600px" >

    <div style="background-color: #808080;margin-left: 50px;margin-right: 50px; padding: 30px;">

    <pre>{{ priceSlider | json }}</pre>

    <rzslider
        rz-slider-floor="priceSlider.floor"
        rz-slider-ceil="priceSlider.ceil"
        rz-slider-model="priceSlider.min"
        rz-slider-high="priceSlider.max"
        rz-slider-step="{{priceSlider.step}}"></rzslider>

      <div class="info" ng-repeat="p in products">
                {{p.name}}
                {{p.height}}
            </div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

**My App.js**
//app

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['rzModule']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.priceSlider = {
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    ceil: 20,
    floor: 0,
    step: 1
  };  

$scope.products = [
        {
            name: 'one',
                        height: '00'
                    },
          {
            name: 'two',
                        height: '10'
                    },
          {
            name: 'three',
                        height: '20'
                    }
  ];

});
```

Since I have to call to some outside sources and have a ton of css in this aswell, here is a **[codepen link](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/RNevYq?editors=101)**

I have been trying to solve this for days and am starting to question if it's even possible!
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following function to your controller:

```
  $scope.minFilter = function (p) {
        return p.height >= $scope.priceSlider.min;
    };

   $scope.maxFilter = function (p) {
        return p.height <= $scope.priceSlider.max;
    };
```

Then use these filters in your ng-repeat:

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="p in products | filter:minFilter | filter:maxFilter ">
```

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgYzze

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes :')

Answer (score 3):

You need to write your own [AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in order to acheive that.

In your Javascript

```
app.filter('onlyProductsWithinHeights', function(){
    return function(products, minHeight, maxHeight){
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(products, function(product){
            if(product.height >= minHeight && product.height <= maxHeight)
                filtered.push(product);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
};
```

In your Markup

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="p in products | onlyProductsWithinHeights:priceSlider.min:priceSlider.max">
    {{p.name}}
    {{p.height}}
</div>
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be a custom filter, I wasn't sure how to tell it to only display between a min and max height