# Angular filter in ng-repeat with deep object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am following this question to filter ng-repeat by a field

[ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

However my case is different, it's actually a field in the object value of the main object. Basically I want to show only `data.a == 1`

The following code works on the first list. The second list gives me error:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        name: "John",
        data: {
            a: 1
        }
    }, {
        name: "Lee",
        data: {
            a: 2
        }
    }, {
        name: "Rue",
        data: {
            a: 3
        }
    }, {
        name: "Peter",
        data: {
            a: 1
        }
    }];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>List 1</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</p>
    <h1>List 2</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {data.a :1}">{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nh4GryqZJbEiXSzMzTKk

Any help on how to do this or is there a nicer way?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried `angular.filter` filterBy and it didn't work either. Giving me blank array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nh4GryqZJbEiXSzMzTKk?p=preview

```
    <p ng-repeat="item in items | filterBy: ['item.data.a'] :1">{{ item.name }}</p>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried this below

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {data :{a:1}}">{{ item.name }}</p>
```

It seems to work but I need exact match, not substring match. I read this but not seem to find a way to add `true` [AngularJS Filter Exact Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480526/angularjs-filter-exact-match)

Any clue?

**UPDATE 3 (CORRECT ANSWER):**

This works http://plnkr.co/edit/qJl6MtY6fOlVtD9Rv999?p=preview

Basically I added this to the controller

```
$scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {data :{a:1}}, true);
```

and do `ng-repeat` on `filteredItems` instead. I don't see a way to pass `true` param in the view directly.

Comment: If you are using \ can upgrade to angular 1.3, then you can use this:
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter 
These are faster. In particular, you can use https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby

Comment: Another way would be to use a custom function. See my answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034234/filter-an-angular-js-array-based-on-range/29034493#29034493

Comment: I can't load your plunkr, but I think you could also change your filter to be an exact match 
filter: {data.a :1}:true

Comment: plnkr.co is having trouble at the moment. I assume filterBy is the right one to use? https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby

Comment: Yes, I agree (see top comment).

Comment: hmm I just tried on local code and its not working. Giving me blank array. See Update above

Comment: Have you tried: 
 <p ng-repeat="item in items | filterBy: ['data.a'] :1">{{ item.name }}</p>

Comment: I tried this and it works. I'm unable to fork the plunkr it currently

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rqZ5l0wr5wlPwnIWUQ2Z?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access the inner property you need to access it with object notation:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {data :{a:1}}">{{ item.name }}</p>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qe6JRSum1BChl0vWYK2v?p=preview).

Comment: Nice. This almost work but if I change a to 12 somewhere, it matches that also. How to match exact number? http://plnkr.co/edit/iBBq3x2HLUfbUBO3HUJJ?p=preview

Comment: I tried this `<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {'data' :{'a':1}}: true">{{ item.name }}</p>` and it didn't work like it supposed to.

Comment: My final answer in UPDATE 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using \ can upgrade to angular 1.3, then you can use this: [1.3 filters](http://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) These are faster. In particular, you can use [filterBy](http://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby)

See: [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rqZ5l0wr5wlPwnIWUQ2Z?p=preview)

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filterBy: ['data.a'] :1">{{ item.name }}</p>
```

Otherwise, use a custom function. See my answer here: [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034234/)